# text diff on django/google appengine

Tags: python, django

I am developing a wiki using django which i plan to deploy later in google appengine. Is it possible to deploy textdiff like system in appengine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) package can be useful for generating diffs. It's written in pure Python and it's in the standard Python library, so I'd expect it to be available in Google App Engine.